# computing maclaurin series for $(\sin x)^3$ , order $3$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have a clarification to ask:

I want to compute $f(x)=(\sin x)^3$ by maclaurin series, order $n=3$.

I know that: $\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+R_3(x)$.

So can i say that: $\sin^3x=(\sin x)^3=\left[x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+R_3(x)\right]^3=x^3+R_3(x)$?

I'm not sure about my last part: $x^3+R_3(x)$.

Can someone tell me if that's a true step to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Google for StackExchange LaTeX guide. For example `\sin` for the sine function.

Comment: ok i will learn it, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to be explicit about the kind of remainder term.
$\def\wi{\subseteq}$

As $x \to 0$:

$\sin(x) \in x - \frac{1}{6}x^3 + O(x^5)$.

$\sin(x)^3 \in ( x - \frac{1}{6} x^3 + O(x^5) )^3 \wi x^3 - \frac{1}{2} x^5 + O(x^7)$.

Comment: It is clear how the terms contribute to the powers of $x$ so we can easily see which terms to compute and which would be absorbed by the Big-O terms.

Comment: I'm not sure how did you get $-\frac{1}{2}x^5$.

Comment: @debi: Literally expand and see what you get.

Comment: i had a stupid mistake... thanks:) all clear.

Comment: @debi: Sure. Mistakes are okay. As long as you understand the concept it's good!

Answer (score 1):

Better use $4\sin^3y=3\sin y-\sin3y$

and $$\sin x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^rx^{2r+1}}{(2r+1)!}$$

Comment: why is it better? i just compute by definition.

Comment: @debi, It's better as it avoids expansion of a multinomial like $$\left[x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+R_{3}(x)\right]^3$$

Comment: Oh i see that, thanks. so my expansion was ok? just so i know. and thanks for your simpler method.

Comment: @debi: I would say that your method is simpler to compute than lab's, because you only need the first term of the expansion.

Comment: @TonyK - why just the first term?

Comment: @debi: See my answer.